# PHP Memory Limit / RAM questions

Tags: php, ram, memory-limit, virtual-server

I have a question regarding PHP and it's memory limit. I have an `index.php` page, that requires `memory_limit` to be set to about `50MB` or more to run.

So does this mean anytime somebody visits that page it will take 50MB of RAM memory to load the page?

In other words if 2 clients are asking for the same page at the same time, the server needs 100MB of free RAM memory to serve them?

Comment: I must ask why your index.php requires 50 MB at all. Perhaps you should be doing something else?

Comment: Short answer yes... why are you not caching the generated page?

Comment: Close-Voter, How is this off-topic?

Comment: @JohnChadwick because it's a BuddyPress and is using an old theme, never updated...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sure, I am planning to install w3 total cache and further xcache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, every PHP process that runs that page will potentially require up to 50 MB of RAM.

Having such a greedy index page is not a good thing. You're not saying what it's doing so it's impossible to give optimization tips, but consider either putting the memory-intensive tasks elsewhere, or caching the page.

Answer (score 0):

`memory_limit` limits memory usage for script per one request